# Code editor in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, code-editor

What would be a good code editor for Linux (I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) which combines:

- auto completion for c/c++ (more is better)
- syntax highlighting
- recognizing `include` commands and getting the code from the headers
- not an IDE, rather something light
- simple installation

I am not a big expert in Linux and, for example, it got too expensive for me to install SublimeClang plugin. Another thing is that I want to write the code and then run the compiler commands myself, not just by pushing a button, which is common in IDEs. Also, I don't like VIM.

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to ask a question *more* inclined to start a holy-war than this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Just learn to like Vim.

Comment: Sublime text is quite a nice one also. http://www.sublimetext.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want an IDE then I suggest you install [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) and then install [Notepad++.](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.6.3.html)

I *suggest* [Eclipse CDT.](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) It is a C++/C IDE that is quite lightweight and does everything you've asked. Plus it has a compiler. The instillation is quite easy. Go to the software installer and search "Eclipse CDT" and then install "CPP"

Another one, that is also an IDE but a little be more environmentally friendly is [MonoC++](http://www.mono-project.com/CPlusPlus)

Also, there are online editors, such as [Ideone](https://ideone.com/) and [CompileOnline](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php)

Comment: Eclipse is a good IDE, but it is not "lightweight" at all.

Comment: @vsoftco it is lightweight considering it's features.

Comment: Codelite is a lightweight IDE that can be used with a makefile that you can either execute on the commandline or by the IDE.  http://codelite.org/